When opening an Excel WB \\<server_ip>\<path>\<wbName> and trying to save: "someone else is working on \\<server_IP>\<path>\<wbName>, try again later
When opening an Excel Workbook in File Explorer from within the windows server by calling           \<server_IP><path><wbName>.xlsm  and trying to save the WB after making a change, I get an error message "someone else works on  \<server_IP><path><wbName>.xlsm, try again later".
When opening by referencing a specific disk G:<path><wbName>.xlsm the file is saved successfully.
The user is Admin on the server.
The relevant folder is a shared folder
Made sure that the Excel workbook is not opened by a relevant process.
Tried to open the workbook and expected to save successfully after changing it.
What happened is that, although no process held the workbook, the following message appeared:
"someone else works on  \<server_IP><path><wbName>.xlsm, try again later".

Do you also have a drive mapped to that UNC path - that could explain it

No there is no such path, have to mention that the folder is a shared folder

The anti-virus caused the issue, the system administrators are trying to understand what exactly caused this issue. As soon as they'll get back to me I will update this question. Thank you
